# Protected routes - How do i build signOut where i will need to route from Protected to Unprotected screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to build Protected Router/Auth Flow using this tutorial. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

My render function for the Authentication flow looks like this:

```js
    render() {
        const Stack = createStackNavigator();
        return (
            <>
                {this.state.loading ?
                    <>
                        <View><Text>Loading</Text></View>
                    </>
                    :
                    < >
                        <Stack.Navigator>
                            {this.state.authenticated ?
                                <>
                                    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
                                    <Stack.Screen name="SignOut" component={SignOut} />
                                </>
                                :
                                <>
                                    <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
                                    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
                                </>
                            }
                        </Stack.Navigator>
                    </>
                }

            </>


        )
    }
```

When i have logged in and want to sign out how can i navigate back to Register or Login screen? Based on this flow both of them will not be in my Navigation Stack as i am already authenticated.

From my sign out screen if i try to do i get a error for the above reason. How can i solve this?

```
<Button
     title="Go to Register"
     onPress={() => navigate('Register')} //ERROR DUE TO SCREEN NOT FOUND 
 />
```

Answer (score -1):

Given your solution for authenticating (moving from `Register / Login` to `Home / Sign Out`), try the same for signing out: toggle the `authenticated` state to `false`. This will cause your navigator to drop the `Home` and `Sign Out` screens and render `Register` and `Login` instead.